# How to setup a ubuntu server as a VPN server and a router

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, router

I have search the forum and could not get what i want so im starting a new question.
I want to ask that how can I make Ubuntu system a VPN server that connects to Internet via another NIC.

this is what im trying to say.

```
+--------+        +--------+
| Linux  |  NIC1  | Ubuntu |  NIC2
| Client |        | server |         +----------+
|connects|------->|connects|-------> | Internet | ADSL/WiMaxROUTER
|via VPN |        | to Web |         +----------+
+--------+        | gateway|
                  +--------+
```

how can this be achived?
I have read about openVPN and I have WebMin.
What else will be required? Please Guide me.

Regards!

EDIT: Read about RouterOS. is it worth it?

Comment: Sorry, we don't provide tutorials here. I'd recommend searching Google for this - there are many, many tutorials out there on how do to this. OpenVPN is a good choice and is fairly simple to get set up. Once you've started implementation, please feel free to come back here and ask any **specific** questions you have about the process.

Comment: Oh, and additionally - if you want us to be able to help you, get rid of Webmin. Learn how to do real command-line linux systems administration.

Comment: Thankx for the info but it would be great if you can point me in the right direction... plus i tried webmin and honestly... cmd line is better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [Debian OpenVPN Roadwarrior Tutorial](http://zeldor.biz/2011/05/openvpn-road-warrior-setup/) helps you to get a basic idea of the needed steps.